# Set an image as foreground keeping components in front Java

Tags: java

I have a JPanel which contains several J components, the problem is that if I set a background image with the following code it covers all the components as the screenshots show, how can I fix it?

```
private ImageIcon imagen;
private Image camiones;

public PanelInicio(){
    imagen = new ImageIcon("imagenes/imagenprincipal.jpg");
    camiones=imagen.getImage();
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawImage(camiones, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), this);
}
```

Screenshots:

-JPanel without background [image]

-JPanel without background (the only component visible is the JTextField, because it's got the focus on it) [image]

Comment: I think [The Java™ Tutorials, Using Top-Level Containers, The Root Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html): _"The layered pane [...] enables Z-ordering of other components"_ and [How to Use Layered Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) might help.

Answer (score 0):

I've always had good luck using this to create a background image on a content panel; I notice my class overrides paintComponent() where yours overrides paint(). Don't know if that's the difference.

```
class ImageBackgroundPanel extends JPanel {
      BufferedImage image;

      ImageBackgroundPanel(BufferedImage image) {
            this.image = image;
      }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    }
}


public class Gui extends JFrame
{

    ImageBackgroundPanel content;

    public  Gui()
    {
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File(<path to the file "imagenprincipal.jpg">));
        } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    content = new ImageBackgroundPanel(img);
.
.
```